# WinSCP - Download file from SFTP server to network location, then delete

Tags: batch-file, winscp, network-drive, mapped-drive

I need to write a WinSCP script or batch file that will download the contents of a remote SFTP folder, delete contents and then upload to a mapped network folder.  I know how to write the login part of the script. But I am confused as to what the specific command line should look like.  From what I've read the command script to download and delete the file is something like this:

```
get -delete -transfer=binary *
```

The part that I'm not getting is the upload to the network folder command.  I understand `put` is the WinSCP upload command operator. But how do I use it in conjunction with the network folder location files should be uploaded to?  Also, can this be scripted out in a batch file or do the batch file and script need to be written separately?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "upload" to a mapped network folder is not a job for WinSCP.  A mapped network folder behaves as a local drive. A plain Windows `copy` command will do. So first do your WinSCP download and then copy (it's not really called an *upload*) the files to the network drive.

```
winscp /ini=nul /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@example.com/" ^
    "get -delete /sftp/path/* c:\local\drive\path\" ^
    "exit"

copy c:\local\drive\path\* n:\mapped\network\drive\path\
```

Though, if you do not need the files locally, you can have WinSCP download the files from the SFTP folder directly to the mapped network drive:

```
winscp /ini=nul /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@example.com/" ^
    "get -delete /sftp/path/* n:\mapped\network\drive\path\" ^
    "exit"
```

Comment: You are correct, as always.  I should've been more clear.  Winscp (and script) will be running on the server that the files will be downloaded to and that drive is network mapped.